# Remove an item from a recyclerview when his state has changed

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview, listener

Im trying to implement in my recyclerView a way to remove an item from the list when the state of this item has changed.
Ive tried to implement via the Main activity but it desn't work, Ive tried to implement on the Adapter class via a listener to a change in the database  but it still doesnt work , it never goes into the on DataCHange method.

Main activity : When a new ride request comes , I add it to the recycler view via
resultsTestList.add(mCurrentRide);
mTestListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This step works and the result is added.
I have another activity where a user set the state of the currentride to -1 in the database ( means the ride is cancel or ended).

I would like the item (representing a ride Object) to be removed from the recyclerview list when the state has been set to -1 (or mRide.getCancelled() || mRide.getEnded() == true).

Here is the code :

`````
MyAdapter class :



````

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull TestListeAdapter.TestListeViewHolders holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
            //RideObject item = itemList.get(position);
    
            holder.bindView(position);
            RideObject item = itemList.get(position);
            /*if(item.getState() == -1){
                itemList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
    
            }*/
    
                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("ride_info").child(item.getId());
    
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
                        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                            return;
                        }
    
                        RideObject mRide = new RideObject();
                        mRide.parseData(snapshot);
    
                        if (mRide.getCancelled() || mRide.getEnded()) {
                            //int position = resultsTestList.indexOf(mRide);
                            //resultsTestList.remove(mRide);
                            //mTestListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(0);
                            itemList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                    }
                });
    
    }
        ```
    My Activity class : 

 ```
 

    private void getRequestInfo(String key) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("ride_info").child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        return;
                    }
    
                    if (mCurrentRide != null) {
                        return;
                    }
    
                    RideObject mRide = new RideObject();
                    mRide.parseData(dataSnapshot);
                    if(mRide.getCancelled()){
                        return;
                    }
    
                    try {
                        mCurrentRide = (RideObject) mRide.clone();
                        getAssignedCustomerInfo();
                    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    mEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                    }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    
    
    public void getAssignedCustomerInfo() {
            String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            if (mCurrentRide.getCustomer().getId() == null) {
                return;
            }
            DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("Users").child("Patient").child(mCurrentRide.getCustomer().getId());
            mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        return;
                    }
    
                    if (mCurrentRide!= null) {
                        mCurrentRide.getCustomer().parseData(dataSnapshot);
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference("praticienWorking").child(driverId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    
    
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
                        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("ride_info").child(mCurrentRide.getId());
                   
                        if (!mCurrentRide.getCancelled() && !mCurrentRide.getEnded() && mCurrentRide.getDriver() == null && mCurrentRide.getState() == 0) {
    
                            //resultsTestList.add(0,  );
                            resultsTestList.add(mCurrentRide);
                            mTestListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            makeSound();
                        }
    
    
    
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
    
    
            });
    
    }
    
    private void getRequestsAround() {
            if (mLastLocation == null) {
                return;
            }
    
            DatabaseReference requestLocation =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("customerRequest");
    
            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(requestLocation);
            geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE);
            geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    if(!mWorkingSwitch.isChecked()){
                        return;
                    }
    
                    if (mCurrentRide == null) {
                        for (RideObject mRideIt : requestList) {
                            if (mRideIt.getId().equals(key)) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
    
                        getRequestInfo(key);
    
    
                    }else{
                        requestList.clear();
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
     LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
    
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (getApplicationContext() != null) {
    
                        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference refWorking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference("praticienWorking");
                        GeoFire geoFireWorking = new GeoFire(refWorking);
    
                        if (!mWorkingSwitch.isChecked()) {
                            geoFireWorking.removeLocation(userId, (key, error) -> {
                            });
                            return;
                        }
    
    
                        geoFireWorking.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), (key, error) -> {
                        });
    
                        if (mCurrentRide != null ) {
                            endRide();
                            //mCurrentRide.setRideDistance(mCurrentRide.getRideDistance() + mLastLocation.distanceTo(location) / 1000);
                        }
    
                            mLastLocation = location;
                            getRequestsAround();
                            Map<String, Object> newUserMap = new HashMap<>();
                            newUserMap.put("last_updated", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                            mUser.updateChildren(newUserMap);
    
    
    
    
                    }
                }
            }
        };
`````

```
Thank you for your help
```

Comment: "desn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700** (seven hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry I didn't review my post now it should be good and more understandable thank you for your advice